# Can I change the order of the following words?

Tags: grammar

As for the following sentence:

> For me, to live life without achieving my dreams is much too high a price to pay for security.

I want to know if I can change the order of the words before price, for example, can I change the order of those words to *much too a high price*?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't change the order of the words.

The words 'too high' are describing 'a price' in your sentence.

Not achieving your dreams is a price and, in your opinion, this is **too high** a price to pay.

Your first example correctly states that the price of security - living life without achieving your dreams - is too much.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, [too](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/too) is an adverb that qualifies the adjective **high**. When used in this way, nothing can come between the adverb and the adjective that it qualifies (see note 1).

Here is an example from the above link that shows that **too {adjective} a {noun}** is the normal phrasing for this type of sentence:

> It was too expensive a desk for a child's room.

This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=too%20high%20a%20price%2Ctoo%20a%20high%20price&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctoo%20high%20a%20price%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctoo%20a%20high%20price%3B%2Cc0) shows that there are a very very few examples (one in several hundred) where **too a high price** occurs: some of these are invalid, for example **too. A high price** and many of the rest are written by people whose first language may not be English.

1) this is not completely true: you can insert expletives (which are often adverbal) just about anywhere, for example **too damned high**.